# CUDA - device memory,searching a string in a text

Tags: cuda

I have a string of length maximum 500  characters and a text file of size 200MB. I want to write a program in CUDA to search the string in the text file. My text file is too large and I think I have to put it in a global memory of the device, but what about my string? Which is the best among the shared, constant and texture memory? and why? 
Also I have an array of size maximum 2500. Which types of device memory is suitable for storing it?

Comment: You can't put the string into shared memory directly, shared memory can only be populated the threads of each running block during kernel execution. The source memory must be global, constant or texture memory.

Comment: If you're writing this to learn about CUDA, it's a good problem. But I don't think you can expect much, if any, increase in performance over a CPU implementation -- at least not with a regular, naive implementation. Text search can however be optimized in various ways. A good starting point might be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

For a naive implementation on Fermi:

Store the text file in global memory and the search string in constant memory. Set up a result buffer of the same size as the text file. Fill the result buffer with zeroes.

Let the number of threads per block, *t*, be the same as the length of the search string. To determine grid dimensions, consider the size of your text file and the grid dimension limit of 64K. To cover your whole file, select the dimension for *x* to be, for instance, 10K. Then find the dimension for *y* by dividing the size of your text file with *x* and rounding up the result. So 200M / 10K = 20K (which is within 64K). Launch the kernel with *t* threads and an (*x*, *y*) grid.

In the kernel:

Calculate the offset into the text file as *d* = *x* + 1024 * *y*.

Since the *y* dimension was rounded up above, some kernels at the end of the run must be aborted. Abort the thread if *d* + *t* is higher than the size of the text file.

Else, have the thread load one character at index *t* from the search string and compare it with one character at index *t* + *d* in the text file. If the characters didn't match, store a "1" in the result buffer at index *d*, else do nothing.

When the kernel completes, scan through the result buffer with Thrust. Each location that is 0 marks the starting point of a match.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you write the kernel so that all threads in a half-warp are accessing the same element of the search string simultaneously, constant memory is likely to yield good results.  It's optimized for that case.

Here's some pseudo-code for a simple baseline implementation

```
...load blocksize+strlen bytes of the file into shared memory...
__syncthreads();
bool found = true;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen; i++) {
    if (file_chunk_in_sharedmem[threadIdx.x + i] !=
        search_str_in_constantmem[i])
    {
        found = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    ...output the result...
}
```

If the loop is structured such that each thread is accessing a different element of the search string, 1d texture memory might be faster.

The profiler and/or cuda timing functions are your friends.